# node.js express, a very strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, fetch-api

I have an Express server running.

What i do is upload an Excel File from HTML and then Express parse that file and do some calculating.

In the Excel file, each row has information about address of a User.

For each Address, our Express server will use google map geocoding API to calculate the latitude & longitude.

But, because Google doesn't accept more than 50 request per second to their geocoding API, so i have to use settimeout to delay the calculating.

For example if the Excel file has 50 addresses, so i have to use settimeout on each address to avoid that rate limit.

Here is my code to use settimeout and calculate latitude, longitude

```js
createFromFile(req, res) { 
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    return form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      if (err)
        return res.status(500).json({error: err.message})

      var workbook = new exceljs.Workbook();
      return workbook.xlsx.readFile(files.excelfile.path).then(function() {
        // use workbook
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1)
        var data = []
        for (var i=2; i<=worksheet.rowCount; i++) {
          data.push({
            from_name: worksheet.getCell('A'+i).value + '',
            from_address: worksheet.getCell('B'+i).value + '',
            from_phone: worksheet.getCell('C'+i).value + '',
            receiver_name: worksheet.getCell('D'+i).value + '',
            receiver_address: worksheet.getCell('E'+i).value + '',
            receiver_phone: worksheet.getCell('F'+i).value + '',
            note: worksheet.getCell('H'+i).value + ''
          })
        }

        var delay = function(t) {
          return new Promise(function(resolve)           {
            setTimeout(resolve, t)
          })
        }

        return Promise.all(data.map(function(item, i) {
          return function() {
            return delay(750*i).then(function() {
              winston.log('debug', 'process for item '+i)
              return geocoder.geocode(item.from_address).then(function(geo_data) {
                data[i].from_coord = {
                  lat: geo_data[0].latitude,
                  lng: geo_data[0].longitude
                }
                return geocoder.geocode(item.receiver_address).then(function(geo_data) {
                  data[i].receiver_coord = {
                    lat: geo_data[0].latitude,
                    lng: geo_data[0].longitude
                  }
                })
              })
              .catch(function(geo_error) {
                winston.log('error', 'geo_error', {error: geo_error})
                throw new Error('Address in line ' + i + ' is not valid')
              })
            })
          }()
        }))
        .then(function() {
          winston.log('debug', 'we are done calculating location')
          return res.status(201).json(data)
        })
      })
      .catch(function(e) {
        winston.log('error', 'an error occurred')
        return res.status(500).json({error: e.message})
      })
    })
  }
```

And below is my codes to call that Express API, i used React to do frontend job & used javascript fetch api to request to server.

```js
startUploadFile() {
  this.props.showLoader()
  let data = new FormData()
  data.append('excelfile', this.state.selectedFile)
  data.append('name', 'excelfile')
  var me = this
  fetch(Const.restServer + '/create-from-file', {
    headers: {
      'Access-Token': this.props.access_token,
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
  })
  .then(function(r) {
    return r.json()
  })
  .then(function(r) {
    if (r.hasOwnProperty('error'))
      throw new Error(r.error)

    me.props.hideLoader()
    me.props.showDialog('success', 'Process Complete')
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    me.props.hideLoader()
    me.props.showDialog('error', e.message)
  })
}
```

My problem is when i used above codes to uploading a file on browser, i see two request in express log file. Something like this:

[image: Express Server Log File]
I will provide my codes to log info of every request here too

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  winston.log('debug', 'call api:', {
    api: req.url, requestMethod: req.method
  })
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Token, Web-Admin-Request"
  );
  next()
});

function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  /**
  ** Rest API Middleware check if access_token is valid
  */
  let accessToken = req.body.accessToken || req.get('Access-Token')

  // bunch of codes to check accessToken
  next()
}

app.post('/order/create-from-file', isAuthenticated, orderController.createFromFile);
```

I don't understand why this happen. If I use Postman & select a File & upload, it works fine - just only One Request in logs.

Can anyone tell me what is the reason. I feel like this is a Bug of Express. My Express version is 4.15.2

Comment: You probably want to use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44982171/edit to edit/update your question and add the log of what the Network pane in your browser devtools shows. If that shows the  browser is in fact actually sending the POST request twice, then that wouldn’t be a bug in Express. On the other hand, if that doesn’t show the browser is sending it twice but Express is instead somehow processing a second POST request the browser didn’t actually send then yeah it seems like that would clearly be a bug in Express

Comment: Is it possible that your are seeing two POST requests because the first comes from your `startUploadFile()` function and the second is a default form post (triggered by the same button  that you called `startUploadFile()` from and carried out somewhat automatically by the browser)?  If so, you would need to prevent the default action of the button.  If this might be the error, we could help more specifically by seeing the HTML for the upload and how `startUploadFile()` gets called.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you, but i don't use button in form, i just declare a button and a click handler on it. startUploadFile() is the click handler. And because my api server has different domain name vs this HTML page, if form auto submit it also can't reach my api server.

Comment: Have you determined whether `startUploadFile()` is being called once or twice?

Comment: @sideshowbarker In my chrome network monitor tool, there're 2 requests but the first is the OPTIONS request & second is the real POST request. There's no any other POST request.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, i did put console.log() in startUploadFile() and see just one line of log.

Comment: So yeah then that sounds like some kind of bug in Express

Comment: This problem doesn't show in my development environment. With the same code, i only found it when testing on my staging server.

Answer (score 2):

The `Access-Token` request header your code adds to the request triggers browsers to send a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request before trying the `POST` request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests gives more detail but the gist of it is, as long as your code’s adding that `Access-Token` header to the request, there’s no way you can prevent browsers from making the extra preflight `OPTIONS` request—because it’s something browsers do automatically as part of the CORS protocol.

The reason you don’t see the extra request when you use Postman is that it doesn’t do the CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request—only browsers send it, and only for requests made by XHR/Fetch from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser at a specific origin (which Postman isn’t).

Comment: I know about the OPTIONS request, but what I don't understand is the second POST request. Please look carefully at my attached screenshot, you will see the second POST request. I don't understand why it appears because i just call startUploadFile() once.

Comment: That second POST request overlap with the first. So in my case, there are two process doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally i can fix this problem by passing 'Access-Token' into request body instead of request header (now, my server always receive only one request). Thank to @sideshowbarker because your comment trigger me to do this method.

I still think this Problem is a bug in Express, but because it didn't occur on my local development environment, so i will not send a report to them.